# how to overcome requested resource not found in apache tomcat7x

Tags: servlets

I'm getting this error during servlet execution:

> ### HTTP Status 404 - /Hello/
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message** /Hello/
>
> **description** The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.35

My deploy folder structure look like this:

```
Hello-->
  WEB-INF-->
    classes-->
      Hello.class
    lib
    web.xml
```

My `web.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app metadata-complete="true" version="3.0" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class> Hello</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Hello</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: what is the name of your war file? Have you tried <name-of-war>/Hello ? are there any errors in the logs? What context does it say it deployed the web application to?

Answer (score 1):

Classes in the default package are not visible/importable to classes which are by itself inside a package (which is in this particular case Tomcat itself). As an exercise, try to create 2 classes yourself. One in a package and one without a package. Try to import the packageless one in the packaged one. You'll see that it won't compile. Tomcat is under the covers facing exactly the same problem. It can't find the servlet class. Noted should be that it works only in certain Tomcat/JRE version combinations, but you should surely not rely on that.

Put your public classes in a package. Always.

```
package com.example; // <-- Look, a package.

public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    // ...
}
```

After recompiling with the package, the `.class` file should end up here:

```
Hello
 `-- WEB-INF
      |-- classes
      |    `-- com
      |         `-- example
      |              `-- Hello.class
      |-- lib
      `-- web.xml
```

Change the servlet class declaration accordingly.

```xml
<servlet-class>com.example.Hello</servlet-class>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, the `web.xml` configuration is a rather old way of registering servlets. Since Servlet version 3.0, you can just use the `@WebServlet` annotation for that.

```
package com.example;

@WebServlet("/Hello")
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains Hello World examples and links to decent resources.